# Не могу понять, как написать цикл для этой задачи

Tags: python

Есть задача:

Условие:# Есть словарь кодов товаров

```
goods = {
    'Лампа': '12345',
    'Стол': '23456',
    'Диван': '34567',
    'Стул': '45678',
}

# Есть словарь списков количества товаров на складе.

store = {
    '12345': [
        {'quantity': 27, 'price': 42},
    ],
    '23456': [
        {'quantity': 22, 'price': 510},
        {'quantity': 32, 'price': 520},
    ],
    '34567': [
        {'quantity': 2, 'price': 1200},
        {'quantity': 1, 'price': 1150},
    ],
    '45678': [
        {'quantity': 50, 'price': 100},
        {'quantity': 12, 'price': 95},
        {'quantity': 43, 'price': 97},
    ],
}
```

Задача: Рассчитать на какую сумму лежит каждого товара на складе.

Вывести суммарную стоимость каждого товара на складе c помощью циклов
То есть: всего по лампам, стульям, етс.
Формат строки вывода: "<товар> - <кол-во> шт, стоимость <общая стоимость> руб"

Алгоритм должен получиться приблизительно такой:

цикл for по товарам с получением кода и названия товара
инициализация переменных для подсчета количества и стоимости товара
получение списка на складе по коду товара
цикл for по списку на складе
подсчет количества товара
подсчет стоимости товара
вывод на консоль количества и стоимости товара на складе

Вот,что я вымудрил из себя, но так как к каждому значению словарей я обращаюсь вручную, я не могу понять, как мне переписать все под цикл, что бы он сам обращался к каждому элементу списка в словаре

```
name_lampa = "Лампа"  #Лампа
code_lampa = goods.get('Лампа') #12345
qu_pr_lampa = store.get('12345') #price and quantity

sum = 0

for code_lampa in qu_pr_lampa:
    qu_lampa = qu_pr_lampa[0].get('quantity')  # quantity
    pr_lampa = qu_pr_lampa[0].get('price')  # price

    print(name_lampa)
    print(code_lampa)
    sum = qu_lampa * pr_lampa
    print(sum)


name_stol = 'Стол'  #Стол
code_stol = goods.get('Стол') #23456
qu_and_pr_stol = store.get("23456")  #price and quantity


for code_stol in qu_and_pr_stol:
    qu_stol_0 = qu_and_pr_stol[0].get('quantity')
    pr_stol_0 = qu_and_pr_stol[0].get('price')
    qu_stol_1 = qu_and_pr_stol[1].get('quantity')
    pr_stol_1 = qu_and_pr_stol[1].get('price')
    print(name_stol)
    print(code_stol)
    sum = qu_stol_0 * pr_stol_0
    print(name_stol)
    print(code_stol)
    sum = qu_stol_1 * pr_stol_1
    print(sum)
```

Такое количество print - ов связано с тем, что я выводя каждый элемент проверял его через консоль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for good in goods:
    quantity = 0
    good_id = goods[good]
    sum_price = 0
    for item in store[good_id]:
        quantity += item['quantity']
        sum_price += item['quantity'] * item['price']
    print(f"{good} - {quantity} шт, стоимость {sum_price} руб")
```

Вывод:

```
Лампа - 27 шт, стоимость 1134 руб
Стол - 54 шт, стоимость 27860 руб
Диван - 3 шт, стоимость 3550 руб
Стул - 105 шт, стоимость 10311 руб
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ )